# commander.js integration test for CLI

Tags: node.js, integration-testing, command-line-interface

I've created a [CLI](https://github.com/luk3thomas/wpstank/tree/develop) using [commander.js](https://github.com/visionmedia/commander.js/).

I've written unit tests for all my [source code](https://github.com/luk3thomas/wpstank/tree/develop/src), but I'd like to write an integration test that uses the [executable file](https://github.com/luk3thomas/wpstank/tree/develop/bin).

How do people test CLIs? I can hack something together, but I assume there must a best practice for testing CLIs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up using an [assert](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/debugging.html#ASSERT) function in my [tests](https://raw.github.com/luk3thomas/wpstank/master/test/wpstank.sh).